# Android notifications grouping not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I'm trying to setup notifications.

```
private fun sendNotification(id: Int, name: String) {
    val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
    val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.msg_new_ticket))
        .setContentText(name)
        .setGroup(GROUP_KEY)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .build()

    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification)
}
```

The notifications are sent and received well but are not grouped automatically. The function is called with a unique `id` each time. Testing on Android 8 (API 26).

Any ideas please why grouping does not work?

**Update**

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications?hl=en#bundle) says

> If the same app sends four or more notifications and does not specify
>   a grouping, the system automatically groups them together.

I've tried sending 5 notifications but they still are not grouped even with a group defined.

Answer (score 1):

Though i have the java code ,just make slight changes it will  work fine, you have to first create a summary Notification for older devices , and the newer devices will only use the ".setSummartText" from this  code...

> So,The summary Notification:

```
              Notification summaryNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, 
             App.CHANNEL_1)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.o)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                    .addLine(" Olicia : Hey!,what's the progress of the project")
                    .addLine("James : Bud,Check This Out ")
                    .setBigContentTitle("2 new messages")
                    .setSummaryText("Friends Group"))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setGroup("example_group")
            .setGroupAlertBehavior(NotificationCompat.GROUP_ALERT_CHILDREN)
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .build();
```

> Then add other Notifications

And at last , notify the notification manager  in the following order

{First the summary Notification

Then all other Notification}

Code:

```
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(6, summaryNotification);

    notificationManagerCompat.notify(2, notification1);

    notificationManagerCompat.notify(3, notification2);

    notificationManagerCompat.notify(4,notification3);

    notificationManagerCompat.notify(5,notification4);
```

And for some weird reason, it takes a few seconds for android to group the Notifications

Comment: Yeah, it's also taking a few seconds for me for the notifications to be grouped. I thought I was doing something wrong, until I read this post. I hope Google fixes this, as it leads to negative UX